# extract top 10 from results without modifying the actual query

Tags: sql-server

I have a dynamic query, and i am using exec command in stored procedure to execute it.

now i want to extract only Top 10 rows from result of executed query.

i can't modify the query, i want to extract from the result only

This is the query i am executing.

```
 DECLARE @Str nvarchar(max)
 SET @str = 'SELECT *
      FROM tblC6FD_QueryBuilderMaster'

 EXEC (@str)
```

how can i limit the results without modify the actually query

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx):

```
DECLARE @Str nvarchar(max)
SET @str = 'SELECT * FROM tblC6FD_QueryBuilderMaster'

SET ROWCOUNT 10
EXEC (@str)
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'old skool' way is to have an intermediate temp table...

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (yourColName yourType)

DECLARE @Str nvarchar(max)
SET @str = 'SELECT *
      FROM tblC6FD_QueryBuilderMaster'

INSERT INTO #temp 
EXEC (@str)

SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM #temp
```

... and the 'new' (SQL Server >= 2005) way would be using ROWCOUNT method, as @eKek0 did.